# Двухстраничная форма

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть страничка `Create.cshtml` с методом `Create()` и страничка `Create2.cshtml` с методом `Create2()`.

Как сделать так, чтобы по кнопке в `Create.cshtml` перекидывало на страничку `Create2.cshtml` и уже по кнопке в `Create2.cshtml` это все дело уже сохранялось?

Вот методы:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Test_Run test_Run)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //чо-то делается

            return View("Create2", test_Run);
        }
        return View(test_Run);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create2(Test_Run test_Run)
    {
        {
            //чо-то делается, а потом сохраняем

            db.Test_Runs.Add(test_Run);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(test_Run);
    }
```

Кнопки в обеих вьюшках типа `submit`, но когда я тыкаю кнопку во второй вьюшке происходит валидация первой, а до метода `Create2()` вообще никак не доходит

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема в том, что прописано в Create2 View, а именно элемент Html.BeginForm(). Скорее всего там указан путь к Create View.

Нужно прописать примерно так

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create2", "Home",
    new { test_Run = Model },
    FormMethod.Post,
    new { @class = "userCssClass", data_formType="user" }))
{ 
    ...
}
```

Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: [Создание HTML-форм](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level6/6_2.php)